# Vortex doublet in 2D

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, vortex

I am not from physics background and I am looking for some easy source for learning vortex doublet related theory. Can anyone suggest me something please?

Comment: I can't suggest any reading material, but I would suggest to take any result derived by potential flow methods with a teaspoon of salt. A practitioner of these  methods may disagree, but it seems to me that modern computers and numerical methods have made these oversimplified models mostly obsolete.

Comment: @CuriousOne Totally disagree. Modern computers are awesome, but you still can't get several flow through times over entire aircraft for dozens or hundreds of parametric design studies without potential solvers.

Comment: @tpg2114: But they are used in combination with finite element solvers, right? And the finite solvers are taking care of the hard part of the calculation, I suppose, that is not reflected by a potential flow?

Comment: @CuriousOne No, not always. Boeing uses potential flow solvers to do parametric studies all the time. Many aeroelastic applications use unsteady potential solvers which may or may not be coupled to a structural solver. Perhaps that is what you are referring to with finite elements, but they are solving two different domains. Potential flow is still a very important analysis tool. Heck, we still use panel methods frequently.

Comment: What I mean is that one still needs a boundary layer code to handle the cases where the assumptions of the potential flow are simply not physical. I don't think that panel methods are any more "wrong" (or "right")than potential flow, but they both seem to need to fudge a few things to come close to reality, while a full CFD code (which is what I meant by finite elements) does not have that problem (it has other problems, like slow convergence and spurious modes, though).

Comment: @CuriousOne But for a great number of problems, you don't need to worry about the boundary layer flow. A jetliner at cruise for example. So yes -- potential flow solvers do not have all the physics in them, but for a great deal of engineering problems one does not need all the physics in there. If you can predict lift during design phases, and do it in ~45 minutes on an engineers workstation, you can quickly rule out designs that aren't worth further investigation in either the wind tunnel or a full CFD solver. Which doesn't need to be solved with finite elements (and usually isn't).

Comment: Hence my comment "to take potential solutions with a grain of salt". If you have them calibrated agains reality because you are only making small adjustments on basically understood designs, you are fine. A newbie trying to simulate potential flow around an arbitrary body will soon realize that the unphysical assumptions of potential flow may not cover that particular case, at all.